# Conditional Multiple Fields Searching and Filtering in LINQ

Tags: linq

Assuming that we have the following table:

```
Person:
  PersonID,
  Name,
  Age,
  Gender
```

And we are providing a search function that allows users to search the table according to the name **and/or** the age.

The tricky part in writing the SQL ( or LINQ) query is that the users can choose to search for both field, or any one field, or no field. If he wants to search for all then he would just have to leave the textbox blank.

The logic to do this can be written as follows:

```
var p;
if(Name_TextBox=='')
{
   p=from row in person
        select row ;
}
else 
{
  p= from row in person
      where row.Name=Name_TextBox
        select row ;
}
// repeat the same for age
```

Now after a while the code gets very long and messy... How can I compress the above into a single query with **no if-else**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative which I have used in SQL which could be implemented in Linq too is

```
var p = from p in Person
       where p.Name == Name_TextBox || Name_TextBox == String.Empty
       select p;
```

(Note that your 'linq' is using SQL syntax, which won't compile. Also you can't declare a var as you are doing without directly assigning a value)

Answer (score 10):

Try code like this

```
       string personName = txtPersonName.Text;
       int personAge = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
       var opportunites =  from p in this.DataContext.Persons
                            select new
                            {
                                p.PersonID,
                                p.Name,
                                p.Age,
                                p.Gender
                            };

        if (personsID != 0)
            opportunites = opportunites.Where(p => p.PersonID == personID);

        if (personName != string.Empty)
            opportunites = opportunites.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(personName));

        if (personAge != 0)
            opportunites = opportunites.Where(p => p.Age == personAge);
```

This will work fine. If personName is not given it will be not add to where, and if given then it will added.

Comment: This is the better answer by far.

Comment: I must admit that I think this solution is cleaner too, but I would have saved the select for last - that way you are just building up the query without executing anything (I believe?). So start with var opportunities = Persons, then add the Where's and do Select at the end. And in fairness, this solutions isn't using if-then-else, but just if.

Comment: Caveat to my previous comment - if it was Linq to objets, the whole thing would be streamed anyway, so I think the order of Select/Where would be irrelevant. For LinqToSql, I'm not so sure. In fact I'm not sure at all. Jon Skeet, where are you?

Comment: I am getting the error "The specified type member 'QuestionProcessGroup' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: QuestionProcessGroup is an entity key referring to another table.

Answer (score 2):

why not use the null coalescing operator? eg.

`var products = from a in context.products
                where a.ID == (productID ?? a.ID)
                select a;`

This works really well on my system