# LINQ to Entities conditional where clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following query which works okay.  However it doesn't work in a join query, where it's needed.

```
var ra = from c in _context.Wxlogs
         select c;

if (year == "2011")
{
    ra = (IQueryable<Wxlog>)(from c in _context.Wxlogs
                             where c.LogYear == year 
                                   && (SqlFunctions.DatePart("Month", c.LogDate2) == m3) 
                                   && c.LogTime.Contains("23:59")
                             orderby c.LogDate2
                             let LogDate = c.LogDate2
                             select new { 
                                 LogDate, 
                                 c.Rain_today 
                             });
}
else if (year != "2011")
{
    ra = (IQueryable<Wxlog>)(from c in _context.Wxlogs
                             where c.LogYear == year 
                             && c.LogMonth == mm 
                             && c.LogTime.Contains("08:59")
                             orderby c.LogDate2
                             let LogDate = EntityFunctions.AddDays(c.LogDate2, -1)
                             select new { 
                                 LogDate, 
                                 c.Rain_today 
                             });
}
```

Hence I've been trying to embed the else if conditions ( [something like this answer by Whaheed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005961/conditional-multiple-fields-searching-and-filtering-in-linq/1006016#1006016) ) without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't work how?  Doesn't give you the data you're expecting, throws an error, or?

Comment: The join gives this error:  "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `var` with a conditional operator:

```
var query = year == "2011" ?
                 from c in _context.Wxlogs
                 where c.LogYear == year 
                 && (SqlFunctions.DatePart("Month", c.LogDate2) == m3) 
                 && c.LogTime.Contains("23:59")
                 orderby c.LogDate2
                 let LogDate = c.LogDate2
                 select new { 
                     LogDate, 
                     c.Rain_today 
                 });
// Second part of conditional
               : from c in _context.Wxlogs
                 where c.LogYear == year 
                 && c.LogMonth == mm 
                 && c.LogTime.Contains("08:59")
                 orderby c.LogDate2
                 let LogDate = EntityFunctions.AddDays(c.LogDate2, -1)
                 select new { 
                     LogDate, 
                     c.Rain_today 
                 });
```

It's not ideal, but as you're *also* changing the "LogDate" bit based on the year, it's probably the simplest approach there is - the two queries differ in too many places to be extracted in the normal way. (It's not like you've *actually* just got a conditional "where" clause as your title suggests.)

The reason you need `var` here is because you're projecting to an anonymous type. If you weren't doing that, you could use the if/else block. There are still ways you *can* do that, but it's slightly painful.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  Got the first part to work with a bit of formatting. Much appreciated.  Always battle to get an appropriate title too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can not cast `new { LogDate, c.Rain_today }` to `Wxlog` you need to return `select c` from both queries.

If you want to select only that part you can after the last `else` type the following

```
var ra2 = from r in ra
          select new {
              LogDate, 
              c.Rain_today 
          };
```

Answer (score 1):

try (EDIT after comment):

```
if (year == "2011")
{
ra = (from c in _context.Wxlogs
      where c.LogYear == year && 
            && (SqlFunctions.DatePart("Month", c.LogDate2) == m3) 
            && c.LogTime.Contains("23:59") 
            orderby c.LogDate2
            let LogDate = EntityFunctions.AddDays(c.LogDate2, year == "2011" ? 0 : -1)
            select new { 
                        LogDate, 
                        c.Rain_today 
                        }).AsQueryable();
}
else if (year != "2011")
{
ra = (from c in _context.Wxlogs
      where c.LogYear == year && 
            && c.LogMonth == mm 
            && c.LogTime.Contains("08:59")
            orderby c.LogDate2
            let LogDate = EntityFunctions.AddDays(c.LogDate2, year == "2011" ? 0 : -1)
            select new { 
                        LogDate, 
                        c.Rain_today 
                        }).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but am getting an Ambiguous innvocation error on the Where clause

Comment: can't compete with Jon, I guess :-)