# multiple options for filtering linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, search

I want to have 3-4 options for searching. For now I am using my queries in If statements.

```
     if inputcol1 > 0 And Not inputCol2 = "" then 
         Dim list = (From P In db.table
                     Where P.column1 = inputCol1 and P.column2 = inputCol2
                     Select P).ToList()
     end if
```

and one (or 4) more with another condition but with almost the same query, just one different where clause. So this query is simplified and short. So if I have a really big query it would be a big mess.  And I wouldn't want other programmers to read so much code for just a few options.

Is there a proper simple way to just see if the search option is filled in and query it?

Comment: If return type is same for the above query then create seperate function with the passed parameters...call wherever u want it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to expand your query conditionally:

```vb
Dim query = (From P In db.table Select P)

If inputCol1.HasValue
    query = (From P in query Where P.column1 = inputCol1 Select P)
End If
If inputCol2.HasValue
    query = (From P in query Where P.inputCol2 = inputCol2 Select P)
End If
' And so on...

Dim list = query.ToList()
```

Conditional filtering with `Not inputCol2.HasValue OrElse P.Value = inputCol2` will create a query with useless predicates. By expanding your query conditionally only the predicates that matter will be incorporated.

Comment: What do you mean useless predicates? as far as I see your solution will create an extra query for each parameter, which results in a far more verbose code. In this statement `Not inputCol2.HasValue OrElse P.Value = inputCol2` the compiler will just ignore the filter if the first part of the 'Or' operator is true.

Comment: @WilsonJimenez Just look at the SQL. There you'll see useless predicates. If you don't want to filter on variable1 it should not show up in the query at all. Further, no extra query is generated, only where clauses are added. Deferred execution puts it all together. This way of expanding `IQueryable` is common practice.

Comment: You're right about the deferred execution, that's why I didn't say you were making a trip to the db on each If statement, I'm not just saying that the ternary operator is a far less verbose form of the If statements. I've been using it for years without complain and believe it should be used whenever you want to keep things simple.

Cause in after all, why would you want to have a clean query at the end if you had to build a complex IF - EndIF structure to get to it..

Comment: @WilsonJimenez It may have (serious) consequences for the query execution plan. As you know, I like to keep it simple too. Maybe simplicity is also a matter of taste. My method consists of blocks of code that can be added/removed without affecting the rest. That's a bit harder with chained conditions. Well, the OP has options, that's what it's all about.

Answer (score 1):

It's late now but I am currently working on a VB.NET project and in addition to Gert Arnold's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12601019/2011156), it is important to have the same object in selection i-e. P when chaining because if for instance say P is Project Entity and in your final result (after filtering) you are selecting additional columns or object details like `query = (From P in query Select P.Name, P.Deadline)`, it will throw a Casting Exception because the variable `query` is not of the same structure or object as `Select P.Name, P.Deadline`. Thus, use another variable if you want to have a different structure in your final selection such as:

```
Dim query = (From P in query Where P.Col2 = inputCol2 Select P)
Dim result = From P In query Select P.Name, P.Deadline ... 
'and then displaying it 
DataGridView.DataSource = result.toList()
```

However, I did try creating a New Type by `result = From P in query Select New With {P.Name, P.Deadline}` but it didn't work. I don't know why, I will dig into it if I left with spare time.

Answer (score 0):

You might like trying [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). With this library you have a `PredicateBuilder` class with methods:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>();
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>();
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2);
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2);
```

These are extensions for `Expression` objects, which can be easily created from lambdas.

With such an expression you can do `yourDataSource.Where(expression)`.

Sorry for c# notation, I don't know VB.net...
If anyone would like to fix it to VB, feel free.

EDIT:

Well, `PredicateBuilder` is just a neat syntax sugar. On their website you can find the full source code which is really simple. Unfortunately, in C#.
Here it goes:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class PredicateBuilder
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
}
```

And that's it! Expressions (which are standard in .net, no additional library needed) provide some fine methods to work with them and they can be used inside the `where` clause.
Give it a try :)

Comment: the problem is that i am not allowed to use an extra library. Even though it's very useful for my personal projects. Thank you very much. Do you perhaps have some other answers?

Comment: And look at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx - it's a great explanation of how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with your code.. you just need to change the if statement for a [Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net):

```
    Dim table = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    table.Add(1, "one")
    table.Add(2, "two")
    table.Add(3, "three")

    Dim inputCol1 As Integer
    Dim inputCol2 As String = "one"

    Dim list = (From P In table Where _
                (inputCol1 < 1 OrElse P.Key = inputCol1) _
                And (inputCol2 = "" OrElse P.Value = inputCol2) _
                Select P).ToList()
```

Find more info about this situations on this question: [Conditional filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005961/conditional-multiple-fields-searching-and-filtering-in-linq)